# Clarification of Operand in Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript

I am doing this for the benefit of Javascript but the knowledge and terms cross all languages I would imagine. This is why I included JAVA and C as programmers knowledge on the subject from these fields are generally higher level.

If the question has been posed and answered, kindly just let me know.

I understand the basics of operators and operands.

```
1 + 2 = 3
```

1 and 2 are the operands and + is the operator. Solutions to the expression are not considered operands as they are the returned value.

**If I am wrong with this summary please let me know**

My question is that in assigning a value to variable

```
var x = 1
```

Is the variable considered to be the operand in this instance? My guess would be yes, as x is being assigned via an operator the value 1. But is it not, or are both x and 1 the operands with = being the assignment operator as the solution is x is now 1.

Comment: both x and 1 are the operands and = is the assignment operator

Comment: @shivam Thanks so much Shivam if you'd like to place this as the answer I'd happy to place the checkmark for you. I figured x and 1 were but was not sure. Thanks again!

Comment: In c++ `int x = 1` is a declaration, not an expression, there are no operands but a single declarator with an initializer.

Comment: Careful with the language, because `var x = 1` is not an assignment in C++.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation, as I know this now I am pulling C++ from the section. My apologies as I'm not familiar with C syntax.

Comment: Downvoted for using "bare with me". I'd rather not "bare with you" (look it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is a simple assignment operator that assigns values from right side operands to the variable on the left side.

Example: `x = y + z` will assign value of `y + z` into `x`

So it is clear that `=` is an operator having left and right sides as operands.

Answer (score 1):

The java [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) tells us the following about the **assignment operator**:

> The result of the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable

So yes, the left hand side of the **assignment operator** is an operand.
A little further on we can read:

> Next, the right hand operand is evaluated.

So the right hand side is an operand too!

Although i don't know why it would be important to know if the java developers call the left/right hand side of an assignment an 'operand' or not!

Comment: While I know it seems trivial in everyday use when I find myself reading documentation provided by MDN or other sources I've found knowing proper syntax and understanding of basics essential now.

When relearning HTML5 and CSS3 from the ground-up again I found so many errors in my thought that could have been fixed from proper understanding of every building block. Now I'm not that developer using vendor prefixes with no understanding. Likewise my JS was decent practice but terrible in efficieny and knowledge

Comment: Well the proof that both are operands (at least in java) is in the link ;) hope i could be of service

Comment: Oh, you absolutely were! I just hate to be that idiot that can run libraries but not understand that basic fundamentals. Heck, I'm even back in to BASE-10 and binary reviews now just to remember what I knew 10 years ago.